# libvorbis: segfault when closing block (vorbis_analysis_wrote)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, vorbis

I am attempting to code a POC for encode and decode "roundtrip" of audio to and from vorbis.

The the encoding function is being passed 88200 bytes (22050 samples of floats between -1.f and 1.f). These are being copied to the `vorbis_analysis_buffer` max 1024 samples at a time.

According to the [libvorbis API overview](https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/libvorbis/overview.html), and with reference to example- and test-files in the [/src and /examples directories in the source](https://github.com/xiph/vorbis), `vorbis_analysis_wrote` should be passed **0** as value to tell the *block writer* that no more data is coming. **This causes a segfault, and I cannot figure out *why***.

Incidentally, if I merely omit the 0-value call to `vorbis_analysis_wrote`, no data is being outputted while feeding the buffer (`vorbis_analysis_blockout` returns 0 on every pass).

```
 int writeStreamToFile(vorbis_dsp_state *d, vorbis_block *b, ogg_stream_state *s, int samplecount, float *pcmbuffer, char *filename) {

    int i, ii, e = 0;
    int last = 0;
    int t = 0;
    FILE *f;
    char tmpfile[15] = "/tmp/vbsXXXXXX\0";
    ogg_packet op;
    int size_vorbis = L_VORBISBUFFERSIZE * L_RESOLUTION_BYTES;
    int size_data = samplecount * L_RESOLUTION_BYTES;

    mkstemp(tmpfile);

    f = fopen(tmpfile, "w");

    while (!last) {

        int size_units = 0;
        int size = size_data - t;

        if (size >= size_vorbis) {
            size = size_vorbis;
        } else {
            last = 1;
        }

        size_units = (int)(size / L_RESOLUTION_BYTES);

        float **encoding_buffer = vorbis_analysis_buffer(d, size_units);

        fprintf(stderr, "read iter %d pos %d size %d (%d units) / %d, starting at %p\n", i, t, size, size_units, size_data, pcmbuffer + (int)(t / L_RESOLUTION_BYTES));
        memcpy(encoding_buffer[0], pcmbuffer + (int)(t / L_RESOLUTION_BYTES), (size_t)size);

        if ((e = vorbis_analysis_wrote(d, size_units))) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (last) {
            float *src = pcmbuffer + ((t + size) / L_RESOLUTION_BYTES) - L_RESOLUTION_BYTES;
            float *dst = *encoding_buffer + (size / L_RESOLUTION_BYTES) - L_RESOLUTION_BYTES;
            fprintf(stderr, "last copied byte is src: %f at %p, dst: %f at %p\n", *src, src, *dst, dst);
            vorbis_analysis_wrote(d, 0);  
        } 

        // remove this when debugging is over
        if (memcmp(encoding_buffer[0], pcmbuffer + (int)(t / L_RESOLUTION_BYTES), (size_t)size)) {
            return -1;      
        }

        while (vorbis_analysis_blockout(d, b) == 1) {

            if ((e = vorbis_analysis(b, NULL))) {
                return -1;
            }

            if ((e = vorbis_bitrate_addblock(b))) {
                return -1;
            }

            vorbis_bitrate_flushpacket(d, &op); 
            fprintf(stderr, "Packet #%i (%p) got %li bytes\n", ii, op.packet, op.bytes);
            fwrite(op.packet, sizeof(char), op.bytes, f);
            ii++;
        }

        t += size;
        i++;
    }

    fclose(f);

    strcpy(filename, tmpfile);

    return t;
 }
```

The result of a run:

```
 (gdb) r
 Starting program: /home/lash/programming/projects/p2pconference/bin/vorbisroundtrip 
 ogg stream output 7912 bytes in headerdata
 Created 22050 samples of 4 bytes, last sample is -0.248100 at 0x619888
 read iter 0 pos 0 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x604010
 read iter 1 pos 4096 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x605010
 read iter 2 pos 8192 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x606010
 read iter 3 pos 12288 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x607010
 read iter 4 pos 16384 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x608010
 read iter 5 pos 20480 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x609010
 read iter 6 pos 24576 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x60a010
 read iter 7 pos 28672 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x60b010
 read iter 8 pos 32768 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x60c010
 read iter 9 pos 36864 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x60d010
 read iter 10 pos 40960 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x60e010
 read iter 11 pos 45056 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x60f010
 read iter 12 pos 49152 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x610010
 read iter 13 pos 53248 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x611010
 read iter 14 pos 57344 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x612010
 read iter 15 pos 61440 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x613010
 read iter 16 pos 65536 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x614010
 read iter 17 pos 69632 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x615010
 read iter 18 pos 73728 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x616010
 read iter 19 pos 77824 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x617010
 read iter 20 pos 81920 size 4096 (1024 units) / 88200, starting at 0x618010
 read iter 21 pos 86016 size 2184 (546 units) / 88200, starting at 0x619010
 last copied byte is src: -0.248100 at 0x619888, dst: -0.248100 at 0x688d18

 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
 0x00007ffff78ad228 in vorbis_lpc_from_data () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0
```

Memory map and stack dump:

```
 (gdb) bt
 #0  0x00007ffff78ad228 in vorbis_lpc_from_data () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0
 #1  0x00007ffff78aaa60 in vorbis_analysis_wrote () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0
 #2  0x00000000004019b5 in writeStreamToFile (d=0x603840 <vdsp_e>, b=0x603380 <vblk_e>, s=0x6031a0 <os_e>, samplecount=22050, pcmbuffer=0x604010, 
     filename=0x7fffffffdf60 "0 @") at ./tests/vorbisroundtrip.c:131
 #3  0x0000000000401ee3 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe068) at ./tests/vorbisroundtrip.c:243

 (gdb) info proc map
 process 28458
 Mapped address spaces:

           Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
             0x400000           0x403000     0x3000        0x0 /home/lash/programming/projects/p2pconference/bin/vorbisroundtrip
             0x602000           0x603000     0x1000     0x2000 /home/lash/programming/projects/p2pconference/bin/vorbisroundtrip
             0x603000           0x604000     0x1000     0x3000 /home/lash/programming/projects/p2pconference/bin/vorbisroundtrip
             0x604000           0x69d000    0x99000        0x0 [heap]
       0x7ffff0000000     0x7ffff0021000    0x21000        0x0 
       0x7ffff0021000     0x7ffff4000000  0x3fdf000        0x0 
       0x7ffff7027000     0x7ffff71e6000   0x1bf000        0x0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
       0x7ffff71e6000     0x7ffff73e6000   0x200000   0x1bf000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
       0x7ffff73e6000     0x7ffff73ea000     0x4000   0x1bf000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
       0x7ffff73ea000     0x7ffff73ec000     0x2000   0x1c3000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
       0x7ffff73ec000     0x7ffff73f0000     0x4000        0x0 
       0x7ffff73f0000     0x7ffff73f7000     0x7000        0x0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.8.2
       0x7ffff73f7000     0x7ffff75f7000   0x200000     0x7000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.8.2
       0x7ffff75f7000     0x7ffff75f8000     0x1000     0x7000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.8.2
       0x7ffff75f8000     0x7ffff75f9000     0x1000     0x8000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.8.2
       0x7ffff75f9000     0x7ffff7686000    0x8d000        0x0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.11
       0x7ffff7686000     0x7ffff7885000   0x1ff000    0x8d000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.11
       0x7ffff7885000     0x7ffff78a1000    0x1c000    0x8c000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.11
       0x7ffff78a1000     0x7ffff78a2000     0x1000    0xa8000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.11
       0x7ffff78a2000     0x7ffff78cc000    0x2a000        0x0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.8
       0x7ffff78cc000     0x7ffff7acc000   0x200000    0x2a000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.8
       0x7ffff7acc000     0x7ffff7acd000     0x1000    0x2a000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.8
       0x7ffff7acd000     0x7ffff7ace000     0x1000    0x2b000 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.8
       0x7ffff7ace000     0x7ffff7bd6000   0x108000        0x0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
       0x7ffff7bd6000     0x7ffff7dd5000   0x1ff000   0x108000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
       0x7ffff7dd5000     0x7ffff7dd6000     0x1000   0x107000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
       0x7ffff7dd6000     0x7ffff7dd7000     0x1000   0x108000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
       0x7ffff7dd7000     0x7ffff7dfd000    0x26000        0x0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
       0x7ffff7fb5000     0x7ffff7fba000     0x5000        0x0 
       0x7ffff7ff6000     0x7ffff7ff8000     0x2000        0x0 
       0x7ffff7ff8000     0x7ffff7ffa000     0x2000        0x0 [vvar]
       0x7ffff7ffa000     0x7ffff7ffc000     0x2000        0x0 [vdso]
       0x7ffff7ffc000     0x7ffff7ffd000     0x1000    0x25000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
       0x7ffff7ffd000     0x7ffff7ffe000     0x1000    0x26000 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
       0x7ffff7ffe000     0x7ffff7fff000     0x1000        0x0 
       0x7ffffffde000     0x7ffffffff000    0x21000        0x0 [stack]
   0xffffffffff600000 0xffffffffff601000     0x1000        0x0 [vsyscall]
```

The full work-in-progress source can be viewed [here](http://swarm-gateways.net/bzzr:/b6989dd58e8f4c2189deb396830cd4682836bed9594c251fd4896c8d0a752aa2/?content_type=text/plain). audio data is [here (raw pcm)](http://swarm-gateways.net/bzzr:/5834ae8c64bc1ae72239d8132ac3290e47d327f22c1e45adf948155df5d11ab2)

Using:

- libvorbis 1.3.5
- gcc 5.4.0
- linux 4.4.0-45-generic

ldd:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe7afa9000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f30a9c70000)
libvorbis.so.0 => /home/lash/src/libvorbis-1.3.5/build/lib/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f30a9a37000)
libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f30a978d000)
libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f30a9584000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f30a91bb000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000560df33a6000)
```

Comment: I see you're running `gdb` - could you run a backtrace when it segfaults and post the results here?

Comment: Is your libvorbis compiled with `-g3`? If so, does stepping through your program help? [`vorbis_lpc_from_data`](https://svn.xiph.org/branches/branch_postbeta2/vorbis/lib/lpc.c) doesn't appear to be all that complex and you're lucky that the backtrace is only a few frames long. I'd step through and see why it's segfaulting.

Comment: the end of the so part of the `make debug` is `... -g   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libvorbis.so.0 -o .libs/libvorbis.so.0.4.8`. Not sure how I would go about getting the -g3 flag using GNU configure/make etc? Also, trying to make a breakpoint on `lpc.c` (which holds the function) in `gdb` just gives "no source file available."

Comment: If it's autotools, `./configure CFLAGS='-g3 -O0'` should do it. I'd also throw them into make as well: `CFLAGS='-g3 -O0' make -j4` or something to that effect when building libvorbis. If you're using a system library, you shouldn't be (for debugging purposes, I mean). You're going to get great benefit from compiling it yourself and looking through the symbols on your own, unless you can install the debugging symbols for your system (if you're on linux, you can usually do that but not always). You can always switch to compiling against the system library later.

Comment: This is getting off-topic, but those flags did not help in getting any symbols for a breakpoint or for the SIGSEGV. I was able to install the debug symbols from the distro, but I'm not 100% sure if the source file (I added it with `directory` in `gdb`manually from the source I downloaded) has the same lines as the source of the system `so` (and from what was on the line it didn't look like it)...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137244/discussion-between-lash-and-qix).